# Can Silverlight run a library written in C++ on PC/Mac/Linux?

Tags: c++, silverlight

I have some C++ libraries. Is there a way to use them from Silverlight in a cross platform way (on Linux/Mac/PC)? I don't want to use C++/CLI if possible.

I googled this [article](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/165145.aspx) saying COM is the only way. However, I was told that Silverlight4 supports PInvoke.

Comment: FYI: I asked a similar question here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/94068/how-can-a-silverlight-app-talk-to-another-app-on-a-mac

Comment: I have never been able to install and make silver light work on Linux, and I would avoid Silverlight if you wanted to have a cross platform product which were working on Linux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Silverlight 4 does not support PInvoke so the answer is no you can't directly use your C++ Libraries.

PInvoke is currently expected to be in Silverlight 5 for release sometime this year (2011).

See this John Papa blog [Silverlight 5 Features](http://johnpapa.net/silverlight/silverlight5features/), bullet point on OOB features.

Answer (score 3):

My impression was that Silverlight on desktop doesn't support native C++. Here is a link that seem to confirm it: http://cristianadam.blogspot.com/2009/10/silverlight-for-windows-embeddedhh-c.html

Comment: Silverlight for Windows Embedded is quite a different beast from the Silverlight 4 and WP7.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. Check out also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234395/marshalling-unmanaged-code-in-silverlight).

Answer (score 1):

Seams like most of the answeres only focus on the part of the question of wether Silverlight can run C++ code, however none of the questions appears to address the part of the question of Silverlight/C++ being cross platform -- to the best of my experiance Silverlight runs badly on Linux, so interpreting and summerizing from the other questions then;

- No, is does not work with C++, and
- No, nor does anything in Silverlight appears to work cross platform/browser.

**Update**: Just installed the latest version of Moonlight (Silverlight for Linux), and now at least it works, but it is using 100% of my CPU when active, so probably still not a good choice for a cross platform application. (using Chrome on 64Bit Linux)